# Проставить NULL в пустые ячейки

Tags: sql, postgresql, update

как можно проставить NULL в пустые ячейки.
есть таблица security  с колонкой sec_code  тип varchar.
сейчас часть строк заполнены полезными значениями, а часть строк пустые.
мне нужно чтобы в пустых строках был проставлено NULL

```
UPDATE security
SET   sec_code = COALESCE(NULLIF(sec_code, NULL), sec_code);
```

пробую так но не работает.

Comment: *а часть строк пустые* Пустая строка? `SET sec_code = NULLIF(sec_code, '')`